# Options for servicing Speedplay Zero pedals

Tags: pedals, cleat

I have used Speedplay pedals for ages and I think I am on my third set of pedals. I have the new aero walkable cleats and at the weekend I replaced my old knackered cleats with a new set.

Now that I am on the new set of cleats my left leg (the one I un-click at lights) is popping out of the pedal. It also doesn't feel right and is not a very solid click feeling when I click in and out.
When pedalling it occasionally feels like it half pops out. My foot then feels like it is at an angle. After this happens I can fairly easily just pull my foot off the pedal without twisting.

On my old cleats I had similar issues but I assumed it was because the cleats were knackered.

I have only had these pedals since January last year so I've only done about 6000 miles on them. I have not had to replace the bearings or anything in there. This is 6,000 miles of commuting through London so many stops at lights.

I am going to buy a new set of pedals but I Was wondering if I have any options for fixing my existing set as a spare. I have looked but can't seem to find any replacement pedal bodies for Zero pedals.

Is there anywhere I can post the pedals to that will service them?
I am in the UK.

[image: worn pedal]

Comment: Are you sure it’s the pedal body which is broken? With those steel surfaces it looks pretty unbreakable to me. I’d imagine they are the last part to wear down, you could try taking them from one of your previous pairs and see if it helps?

Comment: I'm not saying broken, I'm saying worn. It does look like the lip of the metal is worn away

Comment: I'd start by emailing speedplay with some pictures or going to a retailer; 6k miles isn't very long; they're supposed to be fairly user servicable (on their own, based on the parts catalog). I'm not sure whats worn either; pictures may help.

Comment: Do you clean/oil the cleats? The one you put down all the time will get filled with bits of old pigeon and Metro newspaper. Take the time to clean the beaks and ill-informed advertorials out of the clips and spray a little bit of lube in there and see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various rebuild kits available on the web, the site [Excel Sports](https://www.excelsports.com/main.asp?page=7&major=5&minor=6) has various options, from replacing just the bowties if the main pedal is sound, or the entire pedal surface.

I have custom length spindles to accommodate foot splay, so I have used both a couple times to avoid the big outlay on replacement.